# StorageException on resuming Firebase upload task through WorkManager

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, android-workmanager

I'm running a Firebase upload Task through WorkManager. On regular progress updates from UploadTask, I save the session uri in my Shared Preference.

When I switch internet off, Firebase handles the scenario itself and resumes the upload task when internet is turned back on.

But when I power off the phone while firebase is uploading the file and the power on, work manager restarts again and attempts to resume the previous Firebase upload task with last saved session uri and gives the following exception:

```
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
     Code: -13000 HttpResult: 200
E/StorageException: The server has terminated the upload session
    java.io.IOException: The server has terminated the upload session
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.recoverStatus(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:354)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:200)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
```

My session uri is saved whenever I get a progress callback from Firebase Upload Task. Maybe thats the problem that I didn't get the latest one when phone was powering off.

Will appreciate if anyone can help identifying the problem here.